# Ignore 'Unclosed Token' in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, csv, xpath

I have a 2Gb CSV file where column 1 contains the time in epoch and the second column contains a 10000+ line XML file (as a single line).

I want to iterate through every line of this CSV and save the second column XML to a file of its own. I also use XPath to get the customers name from the XML file so I can name the file to `[CustomerName]-[time from Column 1].xml`. However some of the XML files are not valid XML and I am getting an error that says `Unclosed Token on Line ...`. Is there a way to ignore that message and just have it skip the file? The following is my Perl code:

```
my $file = '../FILENAME.csv';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $count = 0;
$| = 1;

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    $count++; if($count == 1) {next;} #Ignore headers
    $line =~ /(\d+),"(.*?)"$/; #Load time into $1, XML file into $2
    my $time = $1;
    my $report = $2;
    $report =~ s/""/"/g; #Replace "" with "
    my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $report);
    my $ext = $xp->getNodeText('/report/customer') . "-" . $time . ".xml"; #Generate filename with customer name and time
    write_file($ext, $report);
}
close $info;
```

I am also open to suggestions to make this more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try enclose the troubling codes inside `eval`. For example:

```
eval {
  my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $report);
  my $ext = $xp->getNodeText('/report/customer') . "-" . $time . ".xml"; #Generate filename with customer name and time
  write_file($ext, $report);
};
if ( $@ ) {
  printf "ERROR: $@";
}
```

The following code:

```
$count++; if($count == 1) {next;} #Ignore headers
$line =~ /(\d+),"(.*?)"$/; #Load time into $1, XML file into $2
my $time = $1;
my $report = $2;
```

can be shortened to:

```
next if ++$count == 1; #Ignore headers
my ($time, $report) = ($line =~ /(\d+),"(.*)"$/); # time, XML file
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to put `write_file()` after that if statement? My errors usually come from the XML handling, not the file writing

Comment: It only depends on whether or not you want to to call `write_file` when there is error in the XML processing. If you want to do this, the declaration of `$ext` would be need to put before `eval` with perhaps initialized to empty string.

Comment: You're right. I removed the `$@` from the print because it prints 40000+ characters for the error and the error message is not important to me. Thanks!